# Cannot load Microsof.Lync.Model.dll "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded”

Tags: .net, powershell, dll, .net-assembly

I saw this particular error already at stackoverflow but only for C# development issues. In my case I try to do some Powershell-scripting with Lync like mentioned here: [Change status of Lync by script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213916/change-status-of-lync-by-script).
But I cannot load the module as mentioned (I tried both Import-module and Reflection):

```
import-module -Name "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\LyncSDK\Assemblies\Desktop\Microsoft.Lync.Model.Dll"

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile('C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\LyncSDK\Assemblies\Desktop\Microsoft.Lync.Model.Dll') | out-null
```

In both cases I get the error "This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded". The DLL's are all there. I have installed the newest Lync 2013 SDK (we have Office 2013 installed), so the version should match. Any idea how I can load those assemblies/DLL's? Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? Type $psversiontable to check -- you'll also see the CLRVersion returned there. I bet you're running PowerShell 2.0, which runs on the 2.0 .NET runtime; upgrade to PowerShell version 4 and you should be able to load the Lync dlls.

Comment: What version of Windows are you developing/importing on? Windows 7?

Comment: It's Windows 7, yes (will soon be 8 unfortunately due to corporate changes)

Comment: Powershell is version 2.0